# bootstrap modal flicks the main screen when open or closes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap modal in my project.
when i open my modal, it flicks the main page and when i close it, it also flicks back.

when i closely monitored it, i found, when the modal opens, it removes the scrollbar from the main page and when i close it the scrollbar comes back..

what this video shows, happens to me exactly.
http://www.screenr.com/arpH

is there any workaround ?? i am also not sure what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one worked for me..

.modal-open{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: -8px;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is a **[Known Bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855)** in Bootstrap.

You can also try some solutions mentioned there.

like

```
$('#myModal').bind('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("html").css("margin-right", "0px");
});
$('#myModal').bind('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $("html").css("margin-right", "-15px");
});
```

Comment: ahh i mean i fixed that with some other way that i have given as an answer.